# How do I connect a 4th analog input to a Raspberry Pi Pico?

Tags: pwm, pi-pico, analog-to-digital

I have to connect 4 different analog inputs to the raspberry pi pico. However there are only 3 pins available for usage. Is it possible to use the PWM pins for additional analog inputs? or should i use an external ADC? It is to note that I would like to have minimum noise in this circuit which I assume an external ADC would worsen.

Answer (score 1):

Ihe Pi-Pico has 3 analog channels brought out to the GPIO pins: GP26, GP27, and GP28, for channels 0, 1, and 2.

There’s also a fourth ADC channel, which is connected to a temperature sensor built into RP2040.

You can NOT use the PWM pins for inputs.

You COULD connect an ADC - I would just use another Pico.